# Search form submission and pagination in Scala Play 2.0 Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am making a site with basic search functionality.  Queries contain a bit of information, so I have a `case class Query` to contain the search information.  There may be a lot of results, so I need to support pagination.

Here is the method that handles form submission.  I use GET so the page is bookmarkable.

```
  GET  /search   controllers.Application.submit

  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    searchForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(errors)),
      query => doSearch(query, 0))
  }
```

The problem comes when I want to support pagination.  I would prefer that the URL does not change and only a `&page=i` parameter is added.  However, I probably don't want to go back through the `submit` action on the controller (but maybe I'm wrong here).

How can I provide this?  If I have a seperate route for pagination, can I pass `Query` objects or do I need to break apart all the parameters?

My thought is that my pagination link will go to a URL similar to this:

```
@{Application.search(query, pageNo)}
```

Of course, I can't just submit this to my form submission action because it expects a `play.api.mvc.Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass Query object if you create your own `QueryBinders`. You can check [the ones in Play](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/843f0338fd00ec75d04972cccaf467914ab01762/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala) to see how to do that. Remember to add your object (the one with the implicit `QueryBinders`) to the variable `routesImport` in your `Build.scala` file.

Another alternative is to follow the pagination of the Computers sample (in the `samples` folder of Play Framework release), which uses GET requests and some parameters to move between pages.